# Downloading OS system taking too long

Tags: raspbian, boot, sd-card, pi-4, noobs

I have recently acquired a Raspberry Pi 4B and I have just tried set it up with NOOBS on the SD card the whole process ran smoothly until the download of Raspbian began. I waited for an hour and only 34 MB of the 5479 MB had downloaded and so I shut it down. I suspect the SD card might be to blame but i am not sure. Does anybody know why it is not downloading properly? I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: You are running Raspbian smoothly. Why do you want to download the Raspbian image again? What exactly is the command you are using to download?

Comment: No I just set my pi up and I had installed NOOBS and the setup went smoothly until i started the download of raspbian

Comment: Manav, I think the consensus around here, based on all the problems people have, is that NOOBs causes new users more headaches than it supposedly saves them.  A better choice is to just download Raspbian directly and use that in place of NOOBS.

Comment: Where do I download Raspbian from?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/  <- Looks to me like they (quite recently) re-vamped that and the "Setting Up" help section to focus on Raspbian and have removed all references to NOOBS.  \O/

Comment: Also, note that bit torrent is an available option for downloading.

Answer (score 0):

The Bit Torrent download works much faster in my experience than the direct image download from the website. If you are running Linux, chances are that you already have a client installed for Bit Torrent (e.g. Transmission is bundled with Debian). I use Deluge which works on all platforms.